# Auto role when someone is playing Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to add a role with using `presenceUpdate` event when someone plays

but whenever i try i get this error in discord.js v12
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined`

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my codes:

```js
const yetkiler = require('../yetkiler.json');

module.exports = (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const guild = newPresence.guild;
    const oyunda = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === yetkiler.oyunda);
    const yayında = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === yetkiler.yayında);
    const dinliyor = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === yetkiler.dinliyor);

    const eskiOyun = oldPresence.presence.activities && [0, 1, 2, 3].includes(oldPresence.presence.activities.type) ? true : false;
    const yeniOyun = newPresence.presence.activities && [0, 1, 2, 3].includes(newPresence.presence.activities.type) ? true : false;

    if (!eskiOyun && yeniOyun) {         //
        if(newPresence.presence.activities.type === 0){  
        newPresence.roles.add(oyunda)
            .then(() => console.log(`${oyunda.name} added to ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
            .catch(console.error);
        }
        else if(newPresence.presence.activities.type === 1){  
        newPresence.roles.add(yayında)
            .then(() => console.log(`${yayında.name} added to ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
            .catch(console.error);
        } 
        else if(newPresence.presence.activities.type === 2){  
                newPresence.roles.add(dinliyor)
                    .then(() => console.log(`${dinliyor.name} added to ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
                    .catch(console.error);
        } 
    } else if (eskiOyun && !yeniOyun) {  //
      newPresence.roles.remove(oyunda) && newPresence.roles.remove(yayında) && newPresence.roles.remove(dinliyor)
        .then(() => console.log(`${playingRole.name} removed from ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) `oldPresence` and`newPresence` are already of type [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence). Therefore, you want to replace all instances of `newPresence.presence.activities`/`oldPresence.presence.activities` with `newPresence.activities`/`oldPresence.activities`

Comment: Also, note that oldPresence may be null if there is none